# How to group the data by id and get unique values of all columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have a table with ID and other columns. I want to group the data by Ids and get the unique values of all columns.
[image]

from above table  group by ID and get unique(Alt1, Alt2, Alt3)

Resul should be in vector form
A -> 1,2,3,5 
B ->1,3,4,5,7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get data in long format  and for each `ID` make a list of `unique` values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(value = list(unique(value))) %>%
  unnest(value)

df1

#    ID   value
#   <fct> <dbl>
# 1 A         1
# 2 A         3
# 3 A         2
# 4 A         5
# 5 B         1
# 6 B         4
# 7 B         5
# 8 B         3
# 9 B         6
#10 B         7
```

We can store it as a list if needed using `split`.

```
split(df1$value, df1$ID)
#$A
#[1] 1 3 2 5

#$B
#[1] 1 4 5 3 6 7
```

---

`data.table` equivalent of the above would be :

```
library(Data.table)

setDT(df)
df2 <- melt(df, id.vars = 'ID')[, .(value = list(unique(value))), ID]
```

unique values are present in `df2$value` as a vector.

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B'), 
       Alt1 = c(1, 2, 1, 3), 
       Alt2 = c(3, 5, 4, 6), 
       Alt3 = c(1, 3, 5, 7))
```

Comment: yea got it . after getting 2 column table with id, value. can we convert this into the vector form where name is ID an value is a value column?

Comment: the above solution works. but I wanted to apply for table with100k ids. so is this an efficient solution?

Comment: in data.table method how to convert the result into a list form.?

Comment: What do you mean by list form? `value` is already a list. Probably you mean long form, in that case do `df2[, .(value = unlist(value)), ID]`